# aws cloudformation not able to ImportValue of the exported variable

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create stack in aws cloud using cloudformation yaml files.

Following is a snippet of my first stack file. In the Output section I am Creating the export variable with value of the Lambda function Arn.

```
Resources:
  FileTriggerFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        'Fn::Join':
          - '-'
          - - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${EnvironmentStackName}-EnvironmentId'
            - Arc
            - FileTrigger
      Description: ARC File Trigger for offline files
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      MemorySize: 256
      Handler: >- Offline.FileTrigger::Offline.FileTrigger.TriggerFileHandler::ReadFileFromS3
      Role: !GetAtt FileTriggerLambdaRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref FileTriggerSecurityGroup      
        SubnetIds:
          'Fn::Split':
            - ','
            - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${EnvironmentStackName}-PrivateSubnets'
      Timeout: 300
      Code: Offline.FileTrigger.zip
Outputs:
    FileTriggerLambdaFunction:
        Description: FileTrigger Lambda Function Arn
        Value: !GetAtt FileTriggerFunction.Arn   
        Export:
            Name: !Sub ${EnvironmentStackName}-FileTriggerFunctionArn
```

The Stack is created correctly and I am able to see the export variable in the output.

[image: Output of the created stack]

Now in the Next cloudformation I am trying to get the value using ImportValue, something like this.

```
  OfflineBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: 
        BucketName:
            'Fn::Join':
                - .
                - - offline-files
                  - !Ref LowerBusinessUnit
                  - 'Fn::Sub': '${LowerEnvStackName}'
        NotificationConfiguration:
          LambdaConfigurations:
            - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            - Function: !ImportValue 
                          'Fn::Sub': '${EnvironmentStackName}-FileTriggerFunctionArn'
```

While creating the second stack I am getting follwoing error.

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::S3::Bucket OfflineBucket   Property Function cannot be empty.
```

It looks like the ImportValue is not able to read the value from the exported variable. 
I have verified that the EnvironmentStackName is correct. I have tried to put the variable name directly as well but still the same error.

```
  OfflineBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: 
        BucketName:
            'Fn::Join':
                - .
                - - offline-files
                  - !Ref LowerBusinessUnit
                  - 'Fn::Sub': '${LowerEnvStackName}'
        NotificationConfiguration:
          LambdaConfigurations:
            - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            - Function: !ImportValue ocsdebug-kd-environment-FileTriggerFunctionArn
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the NotificationConfiguration. AWS CF does not support this while creating the bucket.
So now I am only creating the bucket without the NotificationConfiguration and later using aws cli to add the notification configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation of Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) function:

**Important**

You can't use the short form of !ImportValue when it contains a !Sub. The following example is valid for AWS CloudFormation, but not valid for YAML:

```
!ImportValue
  !Sub "${NetworkStack}-SubnetID"
```

Instead, you must use the full function name, for example:

```
Fn::ImportValue:
  !Sub "${NetworkStack}-SubnetID"
```